# How to flip image dynamically in Android 2.3

Tags: javascript, android, css

3D transformations do not work in android browsers under version 3.0. Is there any way I can flip an image in this environment?

The flip effect should be similar to this: http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/examples/card-02-slide-flip.html.

Also, I can't use jQuery, just pure JS to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use that? There's no jquery in there, just pure css3. http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/docs/card-flip.html

If you'll be using images, you just need to set images as a background with a fixed width and height.

Comment: rotateY is a part of CSS 3D transforms, so no luck under version 3.0. I'm starting to think that this is simply not feasible right now, might just change the effect to fadeIn/fadeOut for this kind of user agent...

Comment: Oh. Sorry, I haven't been able to grasp your question just now. That's a little tricky to do in pure js.